# Tweet from Meteor js server

Tags: meteor

Has anyone had any luck tweeting from the server with Meteor (Application-only authentication)? I want to give status updates when there is a new item added to a collection. I'm curious the best way to do this? Is there a good package that you would recommend?

Comment: Can you share the code you're using?

Comment: I don't have any yet. I'm not sure where to start. Basicly I want Application-only authentication, not user authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to have AccessToken of twitter to post, regardless of if you using meteor twitter login  or app-only authentication.

Here are some libraries from Atmosphere-

Official Twitter OAuth lib- just for authentication- https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/twitter

and

Here is Npm wrapper for twitter, which can be used for both authentication and posting status, etc -
https://atmospherejs.com/cscottnet/twitter